# What does the following notation mean: $\Bbb Q[x,y]$?

Tags: functions, notation

I came across this notation while at [this MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21003/polynomial-bijection-from-qxq-to-q) and I could not find its meaning. It makes the biggest sense that $f(x,y) \in \Bbb Q[x,y] $ represents any continuous function on the interval $[x,y] \in \Bbb Q$ and thus $\Bbb Q[x,y]$ is a set of such functions.
However, I am not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means a polynomial in two variables with coefficients in the rational numbers $\mathbb Q.$

Comment: More generally, $\Bbb Q[x,y]$ means the ring (field) of all bivariate polynomials with rational coefficients.

Comment: @EdGorcenski , not a field.

Comment: So if I understand, could the following be the examples of such polynomials? x + y, (2/3)*x + y^2, (1/2)*x + (3/4)*y, etc.

Comment: @dt1510 yes, but also $ x^3 + x^2 y - (2/3)y^3 - x^2 + (1/4)x - y - (3/7) $

Comment: @WillJagy Of course, you are correct. Silly oversight on my part. I was thinking of the field $\Bbb Q$ and had wanted to say something more about it, and got my wires crossed :) Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

Or, it means the rationals adjoined with the elements *x,y*  as a *ring*.  So in @Will Jagy 's  answer, *x,y* are indeterminants and therefore transcendentals. But *x,y* could also be other numbers that are not transcendental (i.e. algebraic), but you would need explicit values.  For example, $x=\sqrt2$ and $y=\sqrt3$ would also work, but these are algebraic (i.e. solutions of polynomials over the rationals). This matters because it results in very different rings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer too.